# Run Blynk server, Mosquitto and Node-Red on RasPi Zero?

Tags: pi-zero, server, performance, mqtt, nodered

Never used a pi before so I'm not sure how powerful they are/how much can they run at the same time. (Yes, I obviously know that it depends on what you're running). I was wondering, is there a good chance of running a blynk server, mosquitto MQTT broker, and Node-Red on a single pi zero? I'm pretty sure they can each run separately. What if I leave node-red off since there isn't any chance of me actually needing it for now?

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: @jstola because I dont have a pi zero right now, Im asking so I know if I should buy one for this purpose or if it wont work.